# Reactjs and localization

Tags: reactjs, localization

I'm currently in the process of learning React, so I've build my little game based on react components and I wanted to add translations for the various buttons needed.
The way we usually approach this is that the texts and translations are handled and edited by the client (as in the people we work for) on the server. Those translations would then be rendered right into the html template so that was it.

In React, however, everything is in js and component based. Does this mean that to make the move towards react we have to change our whole localization system, even on the server? Am I doing something wrong?

I tried having this

```
<script>
var translations = {
    start: "Spiel starten"
}
</script>
<div id="App"></div> <!-- this is where I render React -->
```

but it looks like `translations` is undefined in my React App.js file

Answer (score 1):

One option for handling this situation could be perhaps to pass in your translations object as a [property on your component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html). For example:

```
<script>
var translations = {
    start: "Spiel starten"
}
</script>
<div id="App"></div>

ReactDOM.render(
    <Game translations={translations} />, 
    document.getElementById('App'));
```

As you have passed in your translations object into your react component, you should be able to use it in your template as such:

```
var Game = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <div>
                {this.props.translations.start}            
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: It's weird, it's telling me that translations is undefined on the <Game translations={translations} /> line, even though I can log my translations in my App component.

Comment: What is telling you it's undefined - is it the browser console, IDE, linter, etc?

Comment: The browser. The App doesn't render and I get the react error page instead: "Line 242:  'translations' is not defined  no-undef.
Search for the keywords to learn more about each error." Line 242 is this: <Game translations={translations} />,